# Statistical analysis of array members in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

[array]$a=foreach($l in $l){xxxx}

$a OUTPUT：

```
@{D=xxx;p=x;pc=xxx;d=a;t=0-1} @{D=xxx;p=x;pc=xxx;d=b;t=0-1} @{D=xxx;p=x;pc=xxx;d=b;t=0-1} @{D=xxx;p=x;pc=xxx;d=a;t=1-2}
@{D=xxx;p=x;pc=xxx;d=c;t=1-2} @{D=xxx;p=x;pc=xxx;d=a;t=1-2}
......
```

$a[0] OUTPUT:

```
@{D=xxx;p=x;pc=xxx;d=a;t=0-1}
```

**What I want is the number of occurrences of d when t is the same. And put the number of times into each value.**

After convert to JSON

What i want：

```
{"D":"xxx",
"p":"x",
"pc":"xxx",
"d":"a",
"t":"0-1",
"Number":"1"},
{"D":"xxx",
"p":"x",
"pc":"xxx",
"d":"b",
"t":"0-1",
"Number":"2"},
{"D":"xxx",
"p":"x",
"pc":"xxx",
"d":"a",
"t":"1-2",
"Number":"2"},
{"D":"xxx",
"p":"x",
"pc":"xxx",
"d":"c",
"t":"1-2",
"Number":"1"}
```

Comment: Why does this feel like deja vu?  I'm sure I provided an answer to this in another variation of the question earlier.  Did you delete it and post this?  Why?

Comment: @Daniel   Because the version you provided is different from what I need, I think my explanation is too complicated and leads to misunderstanding. I am not sure how to modify it, so I deleted it and asked again. Thank you for your previous answers.

Comment: How do you mean different from what you need?  The output was identical to the output you said you wanted

Comment: You want to count "occurrences of d when t is equal" - when t is equal _to what_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here again is basically the same answer, but now, not specific at all to your  real question.

```
# recreate the array of objects (renamed d to d2 - cannot have duplicate property names
$a = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{D = 'xxx'; p = 'x'; pc = 'xxx'; d2 = 'a'; t = '0-1' }
    [pscustomobject]@{D = 'xxx'; p = 'x'; pc = 'xxx'; d2 = 'b'; t = '0-1' }
    [pscustomobject]@{D = 'xxx'; p = 'x'; pc = 'xxx'; d2 = 'b'; t = '0-1' }
    [pscustomobject]@{D = 'xxx'; p = 'x'; pc = 'xxx'; d2 = 'a'; t = '1-2' }
    [pscustomobject]@{D = 'xxx'; p = 'x'; pc = 'xxx'; d2 = 'c'; t = '1-2' }
    [pscustomobject]@{D = 'xxx'; p = 'x'; pc = 'xxx'; d2 = 'a'; t = '1-2' }
)

# use group-object to group the objects by properties d2 and t
# get the count of the group and add it to first item in the group
# then output one item per group with the new count property
# last, pipe to ConvertTo-Json to create the json
$a | Group-Object d2, t |
    ForEach-Object {
        $item = $_.Group[0]
        $item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Number' -NotePropertyValue $_.Group.Count
        $item
    } | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "D":  "xxx",
        "p":  "x",
        "pc":  "xxx",
        "d2":  "a",
        "t":  "0-1",
        "Number":  1
    },
    {
        "D":  "xxx",
        "p":  "x",
        "pc":  "xxx",
        "d2":  "b",
        "t":  "0-1",
        "Number":  2
    },
    {
        "D":  "xxx",
        "p":  "x",
        "pc":  "xxx",
        "d2":  "a",
        "t":  "1-2",
        "Number":  2
    },
    {
        "D":  "xxx",
        "p":  "x",
        "pc":  "xxx",
        "d2":  "c",
        "t":  "1-2",
        "Number":  1
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you.   how can I minus members?
what I want now: 
`$a | Group-Object d2, t |
    ForEach-Object {
        $item = $_.Group[0]
        $item | **Minus-Member** -NotePropertyName 'Number' -NotePropertyValue $_.Group.Count
        $item
    } | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: So you don't actually want the Number property?  Just remove the line `$item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Number' -NotePropertyValue $_.Group.Count`

Comment: No, I need it. But at the same time, I also want to subtract a member from the end to prevent him from outputting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078295/how-can-i-minus-member-in-powershell

Comment: You're welcome.  Happy you finally got what you wanted.